# Split string into list by outermost curly brackets

Tags: python

I have string

`input_str = '{ "key1": 123, "key2": "val" }, { "key3": 345, "key4": {"key5": "val"} }'`

I would like to split it into list by outermost curly brackets:

`input_list = ['{ "key1": 123, "key2": "val" }', { "key3": 345, "key4": {"key5": "val"} }]`

I wrote this code to obtain it:

```
input_str  = '{ "key1": 123, "key2": "val" }, { "key3": 345, "key4": {"key5": "val"} }' 
input_list = []
counter = 0
current_str = ''
for char in input_str:
  if char == '{':
    counter += 1
  if char == '}':
    counter -= 1
  if counter == 0:
    if current_str:
      current_str += char
      input_list.append(current_str)
      current_str = ''
  else:
    current_str += char
print(input_list)
```

Is there any more pythonic way to do it?

Comment: No, I think this is about as good as you'll get. This is a very niche use case – usually you would want to parse the entire thing into an object.

Comment: Is this JSON? If so, maybe you could do something like `[json.dumps(item) for item in json.loads(input_str)]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands The input is not a dictionary

Comment: Replace `}, {` with `}BANANAS{` and then split on BANANAS.

Comment: @DaniMesejo the input is a string (but i agree dupe is not quite right)

Comment: @JohnGordon "Banana split" :)

Comment: Unless idea is to practice something, The whole input looks sort of wrong. Why that is a string that is so close to JSON but is not? In any case, one way to handle that is wrap it inside `[ .. ]` and then use `json.loads`, do necessary operations and get back to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your input is a valid Python tuple of dicts and the expected output is a list of JSON strings, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the string, and map each resulting sub-dict to `json.dumps`:

```
import ast
import json
print(list(map(json.dumps, literal_eval(input_str))))
```

This outputs:

```
['{"key1": 123, "key2": "val"}', '{"key3": 345, "key4": {"key5": "val"}}']
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but what should I do if it is not valid? Is there any option to check it?

Comment: @kekereke You should include such a requirement in your question. Please update your question with a sample "invalid" input and how you want it handled.

Comment: @JvdV `eval` is inherently insecure (as it allows arbitrary code execution) and doesn't actually produce the output the OP asks for.

Comment: @JvdV Your output is *list of dictionaries* but OP wanted *list of strings*